# SSH to Linux using Public Key

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

I have a public key of a Linux machine.
Now i want to SSH to this linux machine using this Public key.

How should i SSH in this Linux machine from my Windows10 machine using command prompt ?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work this way. The **public** key is named for a reason - you need the **private key** to connect.

It's **impossible** to connect with **only the public** key.

You should have two keys making up the keypair (e.g. for ED25519):

- id_ed25519

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW[...]
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

- id_ed25519.pub

```
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIG52XtjUkLe5oKTlF5JcOXPV+xM3OeHGDn4KheTm7Gkl user@host
```

You need the one where the contents say "PRIVATE KEY".

Establish a connection with:

```sh
ssh -i id_ed25519 user@host
```

Alternatively, if you are using [PuTTY](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/latest.html), you may have a .ppk file - this contains the private key as well.

Here's a [link](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/windows/puttygen/#how-to-set-up-putty-ssh-keys-for-passwordless-logins-using-pagent) helping you use PuTTY with SSH keys. It's even possible to import OpenSSH generated keys to [PuTTY *.ppk files](https://www.simplified.guide/putty/convert-ssh-key-to-ppk).

Comment: Can you please let me know how should i use that public key to SSH in linux?

Comment: Again: If you only have a *public* key, you can't. Please check whether you didn't miss something.

Comment: So i have to Ask for Private Key to SSH OR else i have to generate private and public key using puttygen,then copy the public in authorized_key of .ssh and then SSH using private key.Is this understanding correct of both approach ?

Comment: Generating your keypair and only handing out public keys is the correct way. Be wary of services that generate private keys for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your key pair , easiest is with PuTTY. Follow the link of @fuero.

Then create a user on the Linux instance:

```
useradd -m <username>
```

Replace **<username>** with the username you want

Create a directory in your user folder:

```
cd ~username
mkdir .ssh
```

Copy the public key into a new file that you name "authorized_keys":

```
echo 'ssh-rsa [...] user@host' >> ~username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

( You paste the content of the public key previously generated by puTTY in OpenSSH format )

Change the permissions on folder and file:

```
chown -R username:username /home/username/.ssh
chmod -R u=rwX,go= /home/username/.ssh
```

If you happen to have a SELinux enabled system, throw in

```
restorecon -R /home/usernmae
```

Finally check the output to see if all good:

```
grep  PubkeyAuthentication /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

The output should be: `PubkeyAuthentication yes`

Comment: `ssh-copy-id -i <private_key_file>` should be preferred if password auth is available for provisioning. Saves a lot of headache if you get the permissions wrong.